# Finding a simple module over $R = M_2(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, soft-question

Finding a simple module over $R = M_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

So, I don't think that we can use any ideals of $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$, because I believe $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is already simple. It is a common result that ideals of $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ are of the form $M_2(I)$ where $I \triangleleft \mathbb{Q}$, and since $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is a field it has no non-trivial ideals.

Anyway, insight is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Does $M_2(\mathbb Q)$ denote the matrix ring over the rationals? Because that is emphatically not a field, as you write.  True, it doesn't have any two-sided ideals, but it has infinitely many nontrivial right and left ideals, which is what you'd need to find a submodule that's simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M := \mathbb{Q}^{2\times1}$ is a simple $R$-module via the usual matrix-vector multiplication. This is because $R$ acts transitively on $M$ (for any two vectors $v, w \in M$ you can always find a linear map $A \in \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(M)$ satisfying $Av = w$), so whenever $0 \ne x \in N \le M$ then $M = Rx \le N$, which means $M=N$.

Furthermore, $M$ is actually the only simple $R$-module up to isomorphism, since 
$$
R = M \oplus M
$$
so $R$ is a semisimple ring, and the direct summands represent all isomorphism classes of simple $R$-modules.

Comment: So by $\mathbb{Q}^{2 \times 1}$ you mean column vectors with 2-entries in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: $R=M_2(\Bbb{Q})$ has no two-sided ideals but it has left ideals such as $R \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}=\{\pmatrix{a & 0 \\ b & 0}\} $ and $R/R \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0} $ is a simple left $R$-module isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}^2$